# Выдает ошибку об абстратном классе, и я не пойму что у меня не так

Tags: c++

Ошибка: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0322   object of abstract class type "AirHockeyGame" is not allowed:   AirHockey

Мой код в меине:

```
 #include "AirHockeyGame.h"

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    AirHockeyGame airHockeyGame;
    airHockeyGame.LaunchGame();
    return 0;
 }
```

Код AirHockeyGame

```
#include "PlayGameState.h"

class AirHockeyGame : public PlayGameStateListener
{
  public:
   AirHockeyGame();
   ~AirHockeyGame();
}
```

Что я не так сделал?

UPD

```
   class PlayGameStateListener
   {
        public:
          virtual ~PlayGameStateListener() {}

          virtual void OnLevelLose() = 0;
          virtual void OnLevelComplete() = 0;
   };
```

Comment: Очевидно, что проблема в использовании абстрактного класса - то бишь класса, в котором есть один или более чисто виртуальных методов. Сказать точно не получится, так как код в вопросе не полный.

Comment: @VTT  одал еще код

Comment: Реализация абстрактных методов void OnLevelLose() и OnLevelComplete() в наследнике сделана ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пока  вы не определите(в производном классе) **все** чистые виртуальные функции базового, ваш производный класс остается абстрактным узловым классом. В данном случаи вы не можете создать обьект `AirHockeyGame`, так как это абстрактный класс. Если вы не хотите переопределять эти функции, то не делайте их чисто виртуальными, если хотите иметь возможность создавать экземпляры класса.  В вашем базовом классе как минимум две функции_члены

```
  virtual void OnLevelLose() = 0;
  virtual void OnLevelComplete() = 0;
```

являются чисто виртуальными. Это обязует их определение в  `AirHockeyGame`